# Which class loader loaded a particular Java class

Tags: java, classloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the ClassLoader loading a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721559/find-the-classloader-loading-a-specific-class)

Is there a way of determining which class loader loaded a particular Java class?

Comment: Is there a reason to know?  What is it?

Comment: You mean other than [Class#getClassLoader()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()) ?

Comment: @AndrewThompson there are plenty of reasons, but I'd think most of them relate to debugging why a certain classloader in some scope doesn't work...

Comment: @robert-harvey the question linked is (contrary to its subject) telling where a class was loaded from, not which classloader did it. the comment above, .getClassLoader(), is the answer to which classloader did it.

Comment: @eis: OK, which question needs the title fixed, and what should the new title be?

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate.  I've already tried the trick given in the answer to the other question.  That shows from which JAR file the class was loaded.  It doesn't tell you which class loader did the loading.

Comment: I want to know because I'm investigating a problem similar to this: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/173612/ Apparently this can happen when two classes are being loaded by different class loaders (see content linked to for details).  I am trying to determine whether that is the case for the problem I'm looking at.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the one linked as duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721559/find-the-classloader-loading-a-specific-class - that thread is not about finding a classloader, but determing "where a specific class is loaded", if you look at the answers